# Oracle SQL: How to convert a number with a comma as a decimal separator to a point

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

I have a table in an Oracle SQL database. In this table there is a numeric field **NUMBER (9,2)**, with values that may or may not have decimals.
**In Spain, decimal values in Oracle SQL are shown separated by commas**. For example:

- 0,22
- 123
- 15,55

How can I convert these numbers, in case they are decimal to:

- 0.22
- 123
- 15.55

I have tried to do it with the following instruction:

```
select TO_CHAR(FIELD_NAME, 'FM99999999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS= ''.,''')
from table;
```

But the results are the following:

- .22
- 123. 
- 15.55

The only one who does well is the third. In the first case, the 0 in front is missing. In the second case, the point is unnecessary.

Comment: You mean the numbers are stored as **string**? Would be a very poor design. Store numeric values as `NUMBER` data type - **always**!

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit. The field is defined as NUMBER(9,2). The settings are in spanish.

Comment: What tool is displaying the numbers? Seems like you need to look at the settings for that and not the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this table there is a numeric field `NUMBER(9,2)`

A `NUMBER` is a binary data-type that stores an exact representation of the number with the significant figures of the value stored as 1-byte per two consecutive digits of the value. It **ALWAYS** uses this (proprietary) format and does **NOT** store decimal points or format the value in any human-readable format.

Therefore, if you have a table with a `NUMBER(9,2)` column which contains numeric data then you do not need to do anything; that data is already stored as numbers and the decimal places are in the correct place.

> How can I convert these numbers, in case they are decimal to: 0.22, 123, 15.55

If by "convert" you mean **store** then you do not need to do anything as the database already stores those values and it **NEVER** stores a format so for `0.22` it will store the digits `22` and that the exponent is `-2` (shifting it 2-digits to the right of the decimal point). Similarly `123` will be stored as `1` in one byte and `23` in another byte and an exponent of `0` and `15.55` will be stored as the bytes `15` and  `55` with an exponent of `-2`.

If by "convert" you mean **display** then you can use:

```
SELECT field_name,
       TRIM(
         TRAILING '.' FROM
         TO_CHAR(
           field_name,
           'FM99999990D99',
           'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS= ''.,'''
         )
       ) AS formatted_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'Spain';

CREATE TABLE table_name (field_name NUMBER(9,2));
INSERT INTO table_name (field_name)
SELECT   0.22 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  15.55 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| FIELD_NAME | FORMATTED_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| ,22 | 0.22 |
| 123 | 123 |
| 15,55 | 15.55 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NV95qpRs)

Comment: Thank you!! It works!!! Sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 with mytable as (
                  select '0,22'  as FIELD_NAME from dual union all
                  select '123'   as FIELD_NAME from dual union all
                  select '15,55' as FIELD_NAME from dual
                 )
                  select RTRIM(TO_CHAR(FIELD_NAME, 'FM99999990D09', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS= ''.,'''),'.0') as FIELD_NAME
                    from mytable;
FIELD_NAME  
------------
0.22
123
15.55
```

Thank you